# How to detect screen rotation on Android in Kivy?

Tags: android, python, rotation, kivy, onconfigurationchanged

I have been searching for a Kivy solution to capture the Android device rotation from one orientation to another.  I have tried both of the window methods below but neither executes the `on_rotate` or `rotate_screen` routines when I rotate the device. I see there is an `onConfigurationChanged` event in java but I can't find the same event handling for Kivy.

```
    Window.on_rotate(self.on_rotate)
    Window.bind(on_rotate=self.rotate_screen)
```

What I do get in the logcat is the following messages indicating the device has rotated but my app never see these events.

```
I/InputReader(270): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
I/InputReader(270): Device reconfigured: id=3, name='ilitek_i2c', surface size is now 1280x800, mode is 1
I/ActivityManager(270): Config changed: {1.0 0mcc0mnc en_US sw800dp w1280dp h752dp xlrg land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.8}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think on_rotate only tracks Kivy's internal rotation (this is done in OpenGL and doesn't relate to the Android level rotation).

You can probably use pyjnius to work with the normal Java methods for this, but I don't know the details. A simple solution that may work just as well is to watch `Window.size` (`from kivy.core.window import Window`) - this should detect the change from portrait to landscape.